# How to combine target selector arguments with OR, not AND?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When multiple target selector arguments are listed, it selects a player who only meets all the criteria listed in the target selector.

How can I make it so that the target selector is valid if *at least one* condition is true, not all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that. You have two options:

1. Have one command per possibility.
2. Invert the check and the arguments (not always applicable):

   ```
   /execute unless @s[tag=!a,tag=!b,tag=!c] run […]
   ```

That command runs if you have either tag `a` or tag `b` or tag `c`, because it says "do not run this if I do not have `a` and do not have `b` and do not have `c`, otherwise run it".

Comment: Firstly, you can't for example do `if(a&&b||c)`, secondly this doesn't work if you need it in `at` or `facing` or anything else in which the `as` reference needs to stay on something else.