# How can I run a command if one or more conditions in /execute are satisfied?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft 1.16.1, I’m trying to make a system thats detects when one of several fake players doesnt have a specific score.
Here is my first attempt:

```
execute unless score sticks_have page-2 matches 2.. unless score plank_have page-2 matches 1.. run ...
```

After trying this, I realized that *all* scores need to be in the correct range before it runs the command! But I want it to run the command when *any* of the scores are in range.

I thought of using the following command, but it doesn’t detect fake players:

```
execute unless entity @a[scores={sticks_have=2..,plank_have=1..}] run...
```

I know I can use multiple command blocks, but I would rather not, just do I can conserve space.

What can I do?

Comment: psst... the 2nd command also combines the scores using AND, not OR! So even if it *could* detect fake players, it wouldn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, combining `if` and `unless` arguments using OR is hard to achieve. Most of the time, you'll have to have one command per possibility. When you have many different possibilities, try using [functions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Function_(Java_Edition))<sup>1</sup> for each possibility.

<sup>1<sub>If you are using older versions of Minecraft, you'll need to find the correct version of the page in the history.</sub></sup>

A similar problem exists when trying to combine target selector arguments using OR. See the other question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/370549/250180).

Answer (score 0):

In your case you only need two commands, not one per case, by using AND and inverting the result. I assume here that you want to trigger something if either `page-2` of `sticks_have` is in `2..` or `page-2` of `plank_have` is in `1..` (weird naming scheme BTW).

```
/execute unless score sticks_have page-2 matches 2.. unless score plank_have page-2 matches 1.. run tag @s neither
/execute unless entity @s[tag=neither] run …
```

You can use anything other than a tag as well, of course, as long as you can check the inverted case.

Here is the logic table of this:

```
┌─┬─┬──┬──┬─────┬────────┬───┐
│s│p│!s│!p│!s&!p│!(!s&!p)│s|p│
├─┼─┼──┼──┼─────┼────────┼───┤
│0│0│ 1│ 1│  1  │    0   │ 0 │
│0│1│ 1│ 0│  0  │    1   │ 1 │
│1│0│ 0│ 1│  0  │    1   │ 1 │
│1│1│ 0│ 0│  0  │    1   │ 1 │
└─┴─┴──┴──┴─────┴────────┴───┘
```