# Check if player is holding a specific tool (can be any type)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I check if a player is holding a specific tool? The specific tool can be made of any type of material.

**Example:**

```
/execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:["minecraft:PICKAXE-ANY-TYPE"]}}] run say "I am holding a Pickaxe"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a command if one or more conditions in /execute are satisfied?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371838/how-can-i-run-a-command-if-one-or-more-conditions-in-execute-are-satisfied)

Answer (score -3):

/execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_pickaxe"}}] run say "I am holding a Pickaxe"
ID doesn't require these '[]' anymore.

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer my question :(